# How to run a sequence of operations (functions) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Let's say I have a list of values to which I want to apply a sequence of operations until I get a final result:

```
[0, 1, 2]

firstOperation xs = map (+1) xs
secondOperation xs = filter even xs
thirdOperation xs = sum xs
```

Although I am sure there are other better ways to handle this, the only one I currently know is to define a function that calls all these functions nested one inside another:

```
runAllOperations xs = thirdOperation (secondOperation (firstOperation xs))
```

but this is both ugly and raises the problem that if I have 10 operations, turns this bit of code into a maintanance nightmare.

What is the correct way of implementing something of the kind here? Keep in mind the example I gave above is just a oversimplification of what I am facing on my current project.

Comment: When I look at your code snippets I see transformations that you want to apply to an input.  Where are the operations?  Hint:  I think you're thinking about Haskell the wrong way and hence asking the wrong question without realizing it.

Comment: I also believe that is the case. Unfortunately :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can make a list of all the operations, you can then fold the composition operator over that list:

```
foldr (.) id fns
```

Then you can apply the result of that to the initial values.

Though you might need to apply a final reduction step separately.

Comment: Only if all the operations have the same type (that is, `[a] -> [a]`, nothing like `[a] -> [b]`).

Comment: But what if I want something like [a] -> [b] -> [c]  (like in the example above, where the final result is a scalar) ?

Comment: @ephemient: Yup, you're going to struggle to get them all into one list otherwise.

Comment: @devoured elysium: You'll have to manually stitch them together if they're of differing types - though using the composition operator will make things more legible than nesting the functions. `runAllOperations = thirdOp . secondOp . firstOp`. Though if you're mainly doing a map-reduce style thing, you can fold up all the individual maps and then reduce it separately. I'd also be careful about using `[a] -> [b] -> [c]` when you're really meaning "[a] then [b] then [c]" - the arrows have a very specific meaning.

Answer (score 6):

`.` or `$` are way more readable than `(` and `)`

```
runAllOperations xs = thirdOperation $ secondOperation $ firstOperation xs
```

or

```
runAllOperations = thirdOperation . secondOperation . firstOperation
```

Comment: +1 for (.), but I don't think $ is always better than ( and ).